# iOS UITableView resize height / cant scroll down issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Beginner iOS Developer here.

What I have is a UITableVIewController that has 1 section with 3 static grouped cells. Under that I have a UIView that has some buttons and text fields, when pressing one of the buttons, the UIView height increases. My problem is I cant scroll down to see the content that is at the bottom of the UIView

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When the green plus button is pressed, these elements are moved down making room for some new elements to be inserted (which I haven't implemented yet as I am stuck on this issue)

**EDIT**

Here is an example project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vamxr12n6rrsam7/resizeSample.zip

Comment: Could you add some code? Or upload a sample project??

Comment: I have added an example project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that in your method to change the invoice. You only change the constraint of the `invoiceBottomView`, but you are not changing the size of invoiceBottomView's superview, that is the `invoicePickerViewsContainer`. So your tableView won't know you want to use more space of the `tableFooterView` (your `invoicePickerViewsContainer`).

You can change your code for this:

```
- (IBAction)invoiceLinesAddLine:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{

        CGRect invoiceBottomViewFrame = self.invoiceBottomView.frame;
        NSInteger invoiceBottomViewFrameHeight = invoiceBottomViewFrame.size.height;

        NSInteger invoiceLinesTopConstraintValue = invoiceLinesControlsViewTopConstraint.constant;
        NSInteger invoiceLinesBottomConstraintValue = invoiceLinesControlsViewBottomConstraint.constant;

        invoiceBottomViewFrameHeight = invoiceBottomViewFrameHeight + 40;
        invoiceLinesTopConstraintValue = invoiceLinesTopConstraintValue + 40;
        //invoiceLinesBottomConstraintValue = invoiceLinesBottomConstraintValue - 40;

        invoiceBottomViewFrame.size.height = invoiceBottomViewFrameHeight;
        invoiceLinesControlsViewTopConstraint.constant = invoiceLinesTopConstraintValue;
        invoiceLinesControlsViewBottomConstraint.constant = invoiceLinesBottomConstraintValue;

        CGRect invoicePickerViewsContainerFrame = self.invoicePickerViewsContainer.frame;
        invoicePickerViewsContainerFrame.size.height += 40;
        self.invoicePickerViewsContainer.frame = invoicePickerViewsContainerFrame;
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.invoicePickerViewsContainer;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:^ (BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            //actions when animation is finished
        }
    }];

}
```

You don't need to change the `invoiceLinesBottomConstraintValue`, because you will increment the invoicePickerViewsContainer's height.

Then you need to add again the `tableFooterView`, so the table view will know that the size change, and the table will change the contentSize

Now, you have problems with the pickers... But I don't understand why you have the pickers in this view. If you want to preserve those pickers inside that view, you will need to change the constraint of those or its frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. This worked for me. I will try my best to fix the pickers. I am not sure where else to embed them. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you setup the - (IBAction)invoiceLinesAddLine:(id)sender {} and the view within the tableview does not update the self.tableView.contentsize as you add more items. so add these lines to the completion function of the animation function within invoiceLinesAddLines and then twice the incremental height addition (i picked 80 arbitrarily)

```
 completion:^ (BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
        //actions when animation is finished
        CGSize size=self.tableView.contentSize;
        size.height+=80;
        self.tableView.contentSize=size;
    }
}];
```

Comment: A table view  controller already have a scrollview. RipzCurlz, I want to know how you are changing the height of the row. If you only are changing the height of the view, or if you are using the protocol: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: k, perhaps i misunderstood his design. I thought he has a tableview on top and then a uiview below the tableview. RipzCuriz, is your UIView a subview of a cell's contentView?

Comment: I tried adding the UIScrollView but could not get it to work. The changing height code is in the example project I have added to my original question. Nate Ren, I am not sure if the UIView is a subview of a cell's contentView. When I set it up, I drag and dropped the UIView directly below the static cell section.

Comment: Nate Ren, Thank you for your code. This is semi worked for me. It did resize the UIView, however the plus button only worked 5 times and then stopped working, also after the 5th press the 'Terms' and 'Button' buttons stopped working.

Comment: The problem with that is that you are not changing the size of the invoicePickerViewsContainer, so your button is out of the view's bounds. And the button never will catch the user event.

Comment: i actually highly recommend that you change the structure of your VC. you should start with a UIViewController, add a tableview and a scrollview as the subview of this UIVC, then add a subview to the scrollview, i think it will solve all your problems

Comment: I don't thik so.  Because I think that he want to put the UIView like a footer view of the table.